# How to split a string into multiple lines in python?

Tags: python

I am a newbie in Python. I am trying to write a program that prints the following three words (without punctuation) on three separate lines: first, second, third

```
m = 'first, second, third'
no_punct = ''
for x in m :
    if x != ',':
        no_punct+= x
k = no_punct.strip()
print(k)
```

This is the output I had from the above program:

```
first second third
```

Comment: `print(m.replace(', ', '\n'))` also works.

Comment: @j1-lee This might not work if the comma isn't followed by a space

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to remove space, and put each element in a list, then iterate over the list and use `strip` to remove the occasional `','` char:

```
m = 'first, second, third'
for x in m.split():
    print(x.strip(','))
```

```
first
second
third
```

Demo:

```py
>>> m = 'first, second, third'
>>> y = m.split()
>>> y
['first,', 'second,', 'third']
>>> y[0].strip(',')
'first'
```

> [Split docs (`str.split()`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split)
>
> [Strip docs (`str.strip()`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip)

Answer (score 1):

You can print new lines by using '\n'.
So you need to replace "," with '\n'.

```
m.replace(',', '\n') 
print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing it in one variable, you can print it immediately.

```py
for x in m :
    if x != ',':
        no_punct+= x
    else:
        print(no_punct.strip())
        no_punct = ""
```

A one-liner can be

```py
print(*[x.strip() for x in m.split(',')], sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern between words is consistently a comma followed by a space, then you can split by a comma and a space like the following:

```
>>> m = 'first, second, third'
>>> m.split(', ')
['first', 'second', 'third']
>>>
```

Then once it's split, you can take the elements and join them with a newline, and print the result:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(m.split(', ')))
first
second
third
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be like this:

```
m = 'first, second, third'
print (m.replace(', ', '\n'))
```

make sure to include the space after the comma in the replace or you will end up with indents.